# SQL logs showing login that I can't find

Tags: sql, sql-server

Within my SQL server logs, I am showing a successful login to a database from an account (SERVER\loginname) that I cannot find in either Security > Logins OR Database > Security > Users. This login is being used by a program, so it's not a security compromise, but I cannot for the life of me figure out where it is and I need to find it to make an adjustment. I do remember adding this specific login a while back. Does anyone have any ideas for my brainfart?

Comment: could it be a security group membership?

Comment: Is it here SELECT * FROM syslogins ?

Comment: @Gavin I don't have any group memberships associated to this database.

Comment: @Mihai I am not seeing it in the master syslogins table either.

Comment: MAybe delete this one and try on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: What does xp_logininfo show?

Answer (score 0):

if you can try to login  with that account, as it is a windows account follow these steps:

- from START or from wherever you put the Management studio  , hold SHIFT key and right click         on management studio icon.
- from the menu click  "run as a different User"
- now login as that account SERVER\loginname

  if you successful login , the account has to be in :
  select name
  from [master].[dbo].[syslogins]
  where name ='server\loginname'

or
select suser_sname()--  you will see current login account as a result
if you can't login with that account, read the error and start from there.
hope this helps

Comment: I tried logging in using the account and it was not successful. The details of it are: Error Number: 18456 Severity: 14 State: 1. The account is also not in the master syslogins table. It might be worth noting that this is a local administrator account and is using pass through authentication (same login on both app and SQL, and same password).